# Oracle coherence cache config xml Invalid content was found starting with element 'scheme-name'

Tags: xml, oracle, configuration, oracle-coherence

I am trying to define 3 distributed / partitioned cache's, with different back up counts. Below is the xml configuration file that I am using. However, it is causing xml validation time issues.

coherence-cache-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<cache-config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-cache-config"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-cache-config
         coherence-cache-config.xsd">

    <caching-scheme-mapping>
        <cache-mapping>
            <cache-name>cacheBak0*</cache-name>
            <scheme-name>cacheBak0</scheme-name>
        </cache-mapping>

    <cache-mapping>
        <cache-name>cacheBak1*</cache-name>
        <scheme-name>cacheBak1</scheme-name>
    </cache-mapping>

    <cache-mapping>
        <cache-name>cacheAsync1*</cache-name>
        <scheme-name>cacheAsync1</scheme-name>
    </cache-mapping>
</caching-scheme-mapping>

<caching-schemes>
    <distributed-scheme>
        <backup-count>0</backup-count>
        <scheme-name>cacheBak0</scheme-name>
        <autostart>true</autostart>

        <backing-map-scheme>
            <local-scheme/>
        </backing-map-scheme>
    </distributed-scheme>

    <distributed-scheme>
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
        <scheme-name>cacheBak1</scheme-name>
        <autostart>true</autostart>

        <backing-map-scheme>
            <local-scheme/>
        </backing-map-scheme>
    </distributed-scheme>

    <distributed-scheme>
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
        <async-backup>true</async-backup>
        <scheme-name>cacheAsync1</scheme-name>
        <autostart>true</autostart>

        <backing-map-scheme>
            <local-scheme/>
        </backing-map-scheme>
    </distributed-scheme>
</caching-schemes>
```

```
Invalid content was found starting with element 'scheme-name'. One of
```

Any suggestions?

a simpler version of the issue

```
       <caching-scheme-mapping>
      <cache-mapping>
          <cache-name>a1*</cache-name>
          <scheme-name>A</scheme-name>
        </cache-mapping>
    <cache-mapping>
        <cache-name>b1*</cache-name>
        <scheme-name>B</scheme-name>
    </cache-mapping>
</caching-scheme-mapping>

<caching-schemes>
    <distributed-scheme>
        <async-backup>false</async-backup>
        <scheme-name>A</scheme-name>
        <backing-map-scheme>
        <local-scheme/>
        </backing-map-scheme>
        <autostart>true</autostart>
    </distributed-scheme>

    <distributed-scheme>
        <async-backup>true</async-backup>
        <scheme-name>B</scheme-name>
        <backing-map-scheme>
                <local-scheme/>
            </backing-map-scheme>
            <autostart>true</autostart>
        </distributed-scheme>
    </caching-schemes>



  Invalid content was found starting with element 'scheme-name'. One of   '{WC[##other:"http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-cache-config"]}' is expected.
```

so where should i put elements like  async-backup 
or  backup-count  as it these that seems to be the issue.

it looks like they belong inside distributed-scheme ?

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of order of elements inside `<distributed-scheme>`. The `<async-backup>` node must be the very last child of `<distributed-scheme>`.